# Jenkins Fingerprints (checksum) for files with same content

Tags: jenkins, checksum, fingerprinting

We're on Jenkins version 2.60.

I want to verify a deployment copy process using fingerprints. I am working with the Jenkins API to get fingerprints for the build's artifacts. I have discovered that, when there are files with the same checksum, only one of the files appears in the fingerprint array. I need a way to verify the checksum for the other files with the same content as well.

Example: FileA and FileB have same content and same checksum. FileA is listed in the API fingerprint array but FileB does not appear. The URL I am using is: https://jenkinshost/job/webapps/view/myview/job/myjob/1/api/json?tree=fingerprint[fileName,hash]

When I check the fingerprint directly by using https://jenkinshost/fingerprint/49a681ceb33c90077fd3f49912c933ca/api/json, it returns fileName: FileA.

Is there any way I can verify Jenkins has recorded the same fingerprint for FileB? Or is the idea to only verify the checksum is valid for the job and not worry about the filename differences?

Comment: Seems to be a bug to me, same on Version 2.414.1. My approach is to somehow guess missing fingerprints to map to hashes that appear more then once based on file names. A more stable approach would be to build your own `archiveArtifacts` function which creates and archives a hash file with similar content. Or how did you do it now?

Comment: At least for me the _number_ of fingerprints is correct - but `FileA` appears twice (resp. the number of duplicates, I guess). So it looks like when creating the list of fingerprints, the filename for each entry is taken from a mapping `hash -> filename`.

Answer (score 0):

Update: In a previous version I wrongly asserted that a matching hash implies a matching file name. This is wrong because the `fileName` entry of a fingerprint represents the basename of the *first occurrence* of a hash.

---

It looks like fingerprinting is not only buggy but plainly not meant to be used to check integrity or local files, but only for *tracking* access to artifacts.

Next to the fact that file names get lost due to identical hash values, folder details are also omitted, so even without ambiguous file names you can get totally misleading results.

Take the following pipeline snippet to create some files with fixed content/hashes and store them as artifacts:

```java
sh("rm -rf ${WORKSPACE}/build") // cleanup
dir("${WORKSPACE}/build") {
    sh("""
        mkdir folder1
        mkdir folder2
    
        echo one   > file_a
        echo two   > file_b
        echo two   > file_c           # same content, different name

        echo three > folder1/file_d 
        echo one   > folder1/file_e   # same content, different folder
        echo four  > folder1/file_a   # different content, different folder, but same name
    
        echo one   > folder2/file_a
        echo four  > folder2/file_b
        echo three > folder2/file_d
    """)
}

archiveArtifacts(artifacts: "build/**", fingerprint: true)
```

Comparing actual artifact names and fingerprint data you get something like this:

| index | artifact name | content | fingerprint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `build/file_a` | `one` | `file_a`: `5bbf5a52328e7439ae6e719dfe712200` |
| 1 | `build/file_b` | `two` | `file_b`: `c193497a1a06b2c72230e6146ff47080` |
| 2 | `build/file_c` | `two` | `file_b`: `c193497a1a06b2c72230e6146ff47080` |
| 3 | `build/folder1/file_a` | `four` | `file_a`: `75ffdb827341e578959bfcabde3789d8` |
| 4 | `build/folder1/file_d` | `three` | `file_d`: `febe6995bad457991331348f7b9c85fa` |
| 5 | `build/folder1/file_e` | `one` | `file_a`: `5bbf5a52328e7439ae6e719dfe712200` |
| 6 | `build/folder2/file_a` | `one` | `file_a`: `5bbf5a52328e7439ae6e719dfe712200` |
| 7 | `build/folder2/file_b` | `four` | `file_a`: `75ffdb827341e578959bfcabde3789d8` |
| 8 | `build/folder2/file_d` | `three` | `file_d`: `febe6995bad457991331348f7b9c85fa` |

As you can see the `fileName` entries in the fingerprint list do not represent the artifact filenames, but only the basename (i.e. without directory) of the artifact which was first fingerprinted with that hash!

However, it looks like the *alphabetically sorted* list of artifacts and the *unsorted* (i.e. original order) list of fingerprints are still aligned, so you can take the artifact name and the fingerprint hash one by one.

The list of artifacts has to be sorted, because of different sorting of uppercase/lowercase filenames for artifact filenames and fingerprints. For me `sorted(artifacts)` has the same order as `fingerprints`.

This is how I create a map from (full) artifact names to hash values:

```py
fingerprint_url = f"{build.url}api/json?tree=fingerprint[hash]"
artifact_hashes = dict(
    zip(
        sorted(build.artifacts),
        (fprint["hash"] for fprint in client._session.get(fingerprint_url).json()["fingerprint"]),
    )
)
```